# PCL 1.6: generate pcd files from each frame of a oni file

Tags: visual-c++, openni, point-cloud-library

I need to process each frame of a ONI file. For now I want just to save each frame of a file.oni in file.pcd. I follow this [code](https://github.com/Nerei/pcl_old_repo/blob/master/tools/oni2pcd.cpp) but it works only with PCL 1.7 and I'm using v1.6. 
 So I changed a bit the code in this manner

```
    #include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
    #include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

    #include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
    #include <pcl/point_types.h>
    #include <pcl/io/oni_grabber.h>
    #include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
    #include <vector>
    int i = 0;
     char buf[4096];

 class SimpleOpenNIViewer
 {
   public:
     SimpleOpenNIViewer () : viewer ("PCL OpenNI Viewer") {}

     void cloud_cb_ (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr &cloud)
     {
       //if (!viewer.wasStopped())
        //{
        // viewer.showCloud (cloud);
         pcl::PCDWriter w;
         sprintf (buf, "frame_%06d.pcd", i);
         w.writeBinaryCompressed (buf, *cloud);
         PCL_INFO ("Wrote a cloud with %zu (%ux%u) points in %s.\n",cloud->size (), cloud->width, cloud->height, buf);
         ++i;
        //}

     }

     void run ()
     {
       pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber("file.oni");

       boost::function<void (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr&)> f = boost::bind (&SimpleOpenNIViewer::cloud_cb_, this, _1);

       interface->registerCallback (f);

       interface->start ();

       while (!viewer.wasStopped())
           {
             boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (1));
           }
       PCL_INFO ("Successfully processed %d frames.\n", i);
       interface->stop ();
     }

     pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer;
 };

 int main ()
 {
   SimpleOpenNIViewer v;
   v.run ();
   return 0;
 }
```

But it crash when I run it. Why?

Comment: I solved deleting the code line: `PCL_INFO ("Wrote a cloud with %zu (%ux%u) points in %s.\n",cloud->size (), cloud->width, cloud->height, buf);` but I don't understand why? Could you help me to understand? Does the function cloud_cb_ called each frame?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem about getting each frame from a ONI file. I need to use the ONIGrabber function set in the trigger mode.

This is the modified code:

```
#include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/oni_grabber.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <vector>

class SimpleOpenNIViewer
 {
public:
 SimpleOpenNIViewer () : viewer ("PCL OpenNI Viewer") {}

 void cloud_cb_ (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr &cloud)
 {
   //if (!viewer.wasStopped())
    //{
    // viewer.showCloud (cloud);
     pcl::PCDWriter w;
     sprintf (buf, "frame_%06d.pcd", i);
     w.writeBinaryCompressed (buf, *cloud);
     PCL_INFO ("Wrote a cloud with %zu (%ux%u) points in %s.\n",cloud->size (),     
cloud->width, cloud->height, buf);
     ++i;
    //}

 }

 void run ()
 {
   pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::ONIGrabber("file.oni",false,false); //set for trigger

   boost::function<void (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr&)> f = boost::bind (&SimpleOpenNIViewer::cloud_cb_, this, _1);

   interface->registerCallback (f);

   interface->start ();

   while (!viewer.wasStopped())
       {
        interface->start()//to update each frame from the oni file 
        boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (1));
       }
   PCL_INFO ("Successfully processed %d frames.\n", i);
   interface->stop ();
 }

 pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer;
 };

 int main ()
 {
   SimpleOpenNIViewer v;
   v.run ();
   return 0;
 }`
```

Comment: But I don't understand what is the purpose of this function: `boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (55));` Could someone help me to understand?